# RTK Query doesn't handle text response

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

We have a basic RTK API Slice that based on fetchBaseQuery just like recommended on [RTK documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#create-an-api-slice).

Also, there is a backend service that **returns data as a text in a response**, but **declared as a `Content-Type: application/json`** on Response Header. I know this is not a consistent but unfortunately, we don't have a privilege to change this now.

We tried to parse it in a proper way but we can't have any clue about the data, we didn't see in RTK, even cannot reached inside of `transformResponse`. We have saw the expected response when we inspected the XHR/Fetch activity on the network tab and that is the only clue we received the data successfully.

I think RTK doesn't process this data because it is declared as a json on response header but provided as a text, string inside of the body. It is a little bit awkward because we don't see any error anywhere.

Do you have any idea how we can reach the response inside of the RTK?

Answer (score 8):

You can set `responseHandler: 'text'` on the endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

From docs:

> By default, fetchBaseQuery assumes that every Response you get will be
> parsed as json. In the event that you don't want that to happen, you
> can specify an alternative response handler like text, or take
> complete control and use a custom function that accepts the raw
> Response object —

Example from docs:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

export const customApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: `users`,
        // *********************************8
        // this is how you handle
        responseHandler: (response) => response.text(), // This is the same as passing 'text'
      }),
    }),
  }),
})
```